# OS X Yosemite - Nexus 5 - ADB Device Offline

Tags: adb, nexus-5, fastboot, google, android-sdk

I've been trying to initiate ADB commands on my Nexus 5 using my MacBook Air. However, when I type `adb devices` into Terminal, my Nexus 5 is listed as offline.

I've tried disabling/enabling USB Debugging on my Nexus 5, rebooting both my computer as well as my phone, and reinstalling Android SDK - the problem remains. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Open the Settings app.

Choose Storage.

Touch the Menu icon button (3 dots, top right). See USB Computer Connection? Choose that and the next two options are MTP and PTP.

Are they checked?

Comment: MTP is checked.